# How to fillnull based on all the other features

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assume I have two dataframe, they are almost the same except in the second dataframe there are some missing value. (NAN)

I am wondering how to fill all the missing values in the second dataframe.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2.fillna(df1, inplace=True)
```

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna

Comment: Hi, what if the dataframe is shuffled.....Which means it is not in the same order?

Comment: @ShihaoWen: Why not try?

Comment: For example, if only one feature is missing. 
By comparing the rest of the features there are more than 1 choice to fill in null. It's not working.

Comment: If it's not working, post an example set of inputs in your question, with the desired and observed results.  Saying "it's not working" does not help us help you.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to hard code this part myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `combine_first`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.nan],[np.nan,5,6],[np.nan,np.nan,9]])

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[100,200,300],[400,500,600],[700,800,900]])

df.combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
       0      1      2
0    1.0    2.0  300.0
1  400.0    5.0    6.0
2  700.0  800.0    9.0
```